# Deterministic random byte/string generator from a seed in C++

Tags: random

I want a function that, given a seed string and a number of bytes X, it will output a pseudorandom string of length X. But it should do this deterministically. This is for encryption/decryption purposes, and so the deterministic part is important. I don't know where to begin looking for such a thing though because I have hardly any knowledge of cryptography. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important rule of coding cryptography is Never Roll Your Own. Use an existing, well tested and reviewed library. Even if you understand the algorithms and theory, there are just too many ways to mess things up.

Anyway, what you are looking for is called a Stream Cipher.

Comment: Stream cyphers can be RC4 - obsolescent, easy to program, but still useful for some purposes.  AES-CTR - a block cypher in counter mode.  Salsa-20 or one of the other eSTREAM http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/ cyphers.